# Run LibGDX game on ARM-based lubuntu linux?

Tags: java, linux, libgdx, arm

Is there a way to make libGDX compatible with Linux ARM?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'libgdxarmgnueabihf.so' for target: Linux, 32-bit
```

I expected that I will have to at least get lwjgl compiled for ARM but now I see that there are multiple native elements needed.

On the other hand, libGDX supports ARM in the context of Android, so some of the needed libraries are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From that error I'd guess you're on a modern system with an up-to-date userspace compiled with the `arm-*-gnueabihf` hard-float ABI. Android uses the older `arm-*-eabi` soft-float ABI, so the libraries are fundamentally incompatible and you can't link them. Furthermore, they may also have dependencies on other Android-specific libraries/weirdness which aren't present on a Linux system, so it probably makes most sense to rebuild all the native elements with the appropriate Linux toolchain rather than try to hack around it.

To clarify, `gnueabi` is the Linux userspace flavour of the [ARM Embedded ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html); `hf` signifies hard-float, i.e. floating-point arguments are passed in hardware FPU registers - as opposed to soft-float, where they're passed in general-purpose registers, allowing the code to still run on machines with no FPU using software emulation.

Comment: You are probably right. But compiling the whole libGDX might be to much for me. Can you explain what all the parts of libgdxarmgnueabihf mean ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a project for running libgdx on a raspberry pi: https://github.com/chrishumphreys/LIbGDX-Pi which claims:

> Patches and compilation instructions to get LibGDX to use Lwjgl
>   fullscreen on Raspberry Pi.

As the raspberry has an arm architecture this might solve your problem as well.